# What does "data-umgid" mean?

Tags: html

"data-umgid" - I'm trying to evaluate some code and am coming across some elements I'm not familiar with. could anyone explain what "data-umgid" means?

Comment: could you post that part of HTML ?

Answer (score 3):

HTML 5 introduced support for custom element attributes that have the `data-` prefix. They can be used for any number of purposes. See [this article](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml) for more information.

[W3 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

Comment: Thank you to all who replied so promptly. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

looks like an html `data-*` attribute, that lets you store any additional info as an attribute to an element, in this case `umgid` whatever that may be... you can check the spec here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#attr-data-*

Answer (score 0):

It means nothing to anything except code written specifically for the site.

The HTML 5 draft allows [data-*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attributes which are:

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.
>
> These attributes are not intended for use by software that is independent of the site that uses the attributes.

They are almost certainly being used to store data for the benefit of JavaScript running in the page, but you would have to reverse engine the JavaScript to determine what that purpose is.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a HTML 5 custom data attribute. It's an attribute that allows you to assign custom data to an element. More info in the [HTML 5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data). The format is to name them data-* with * being whatever name you like, and they can contain any data you like. Without seeing your page code I can't tell you exactly what it's for, but at a guess it's being used to store some data that's being used by JavaScript on the page somewhere.